# fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path

Tags: php, html

Never see this error befor now! I'm very confused...
I'm using only this part of code for testing what i want to get:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $index = $_GET['id'];
    $nick = $_GET['nck'];

    $db_visited = file("db.txt");
    $open = fopen($db_visited, "w");
    fwrite($open, $index."\n");
    foreach ($db_visited as $line) { fwrite( $open, "$line"); }
    fclose($open);
    //header("location: https://www.facebook.com/".$nick);
}
?>
<?php
$dblines = file("db_friends.txt");
foreach($dblines as $key => $profile) {
list($name, $nick, $num_id) = explode("|", $profile);
?>
<div id="fr_slot">
    <a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?nck=<?= $nick; ?>&id=<?= $key ?>" target="_tab"><?= $name ?></a>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

I'm wondering what is wrong at fopen() for expects parameter 1!
In this case, really, i don't understand... Please, help me!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file` read the file and return an array

`fopen` need the path to your file, and $db_visited isn't the path but an array

Comment: Right! My mistake! :(

Answer (score 3):

$db_visited is an array since file() returns an array. If you're looking to open the file, change:

```
$open = fopen($db_visited, "w");
```

To:

```
$open = fopen("db.txt", "w");
```

Comment: Right! My mistake! :(